# mongodb installation on mac using brew with zsh

Tags: mongodb, macos, zsh

I'm using zsh and installed mongo using: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/

when trying to use mongod --config /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf --fork I get:

```
➜  ~ brew list
gettext         openjdk         scala@2.11
git         pcre2
mongodb-community@4.0   sbt
➜  ~ brew services start mongodb-community@4.0
Service `mongodb-community@4.0` already started, use `brew services restart mongodb-community@4.0` to restart.
➜  ~ mongod --config /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf --fork
zsh: command not found: mongod
```

Can someone help?

Comment: You can try stopping the `mongod` (using `brew services stop mongodb-community@4.0`) and then try the _manual_ start process using the `mongod...` command.

Comment: not working....

Comment: What is "not working"? After the `brew services start...` are you able to see that `mongod` process has started with this command: `ps aux | grep -v grep | grep mongod`

Comment: solution: use mongo instead of mongod

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you haven't set path variable for mongodb. You can set it in `.zshrc` file.

Open .zshrc file in vim using `vim ~/.zshrc`
then paste the following line

```
export PATH="<your mongodb bin folder path>:$PATH"
```

in my case the path is

```
/Users/namardeepsood/Development/mongodb/bin
```

save this file and run `source ~/.zshrc` to refresh the current shell environment.

Comment: you can find it here  **/usr/local/Cellar/mongodb/[version]/bin**

Comment: you might have some process running on port `27017` which is used by mongod command by default, try running mongod on different port using `--port 27018` option

Comment: Well, I just ran this command and now I can't open my .zshrc file anymore. Getting "LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed with error -600 for the file /Users/adminName/.zshrc."

No idea what to do.